# Django admin.autodiscover fails to discover "primary" admin.py

Tags: django, django-admin

My models won't show up in the admin panel, and I suspect it's because `admin.py` isn't being discovered.

Also, all the models work as expected in the application; I can import `two.MyModelB` and use it in the shell, in my web-app, etc.

root/settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'one',
    'two', etc]
```

root/urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib   import admin

print("### Running admin-autodiscover ###")
admin.autodiscover()
```

Note that I don't usually use `admin.autodiscover()`, but it was a suggestion I came across when I was searching for solutions to this. Including it (or not) makes no difference either way.

root/admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf    import settings
from one.models     import MyModelA
from two.models     import MyModelB

print("### This should be discovered! ###")

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('id',)

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(MyModelA, MyModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyModelB, MyModelAdmin)
```

superuser confirmed:
[image]

console output:

```py
(env) PS E:\Django> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

### Running admin-autodiscover ###
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Django version 4.1.5, using settings 'root.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

The statement from `urls.py` is output, but not the one from `admin.py`. I assume that indicates there's some malfunction with `django.contrib.admin`, but it's far beyond my knowledge.

Curiously, making `admin.py` files elsewhere ... cause *them* to be discovered:

root/random/folder/admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
print("Is this one discovered?")
```

console:

```py
(env) PS E:\Django> python manage.py runserver
Is this one discovered?
Is this one discovered?
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

### Running admin-autodiscover ###
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Django version 4.1.5, using settings 'root.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

So Django finds *that* `admin.py` - twice, once automagically and once because I explicitly call `admin.autodiscover()`. But the `admin.py` sitting literally right next to `settings.py` goes ignored.

I can presumably work around this by moving my model declarations into some other random folder's `admin.py` ... but I would really like to keep it where it is, because my project is large and I don't want to put core settings in obscure locations (if I can help it).

Comment: The `admin.py` files are discovered when they are in an installed application. You should register the models for an app in an `admin.py` inside that app, if you want to use a shared ModelAdmin class then import it in the app specific admin files

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks. It raises the question of why this used to work for me previously, but I'm not one to dwell on a solved problem. If you'd like, put it as an answer and get a checkmark.